# Ignore only files on the root of the project on Git

Tags: wordpress, git, gitignore

I am developing a wordpress site, in my **.gitignore** file I put the wordpress core files, among these files there is the **xmlrpc.php** file, on the other hand I have a plugin which contains a file from the same name "xmlrpc.php" so it was ignored too.

How can I ensure that only the **xmlrpc.php** file on the site root is ignored ?

**Here is what I have in my .gitignore file:** 
#WordPress core files
wp-admin
wp-includes
xmlrpc.php
index.php
wp-activate.php
wp-blog-header.php
wp-comments-post.php
wp-cron.php
wp-links-opml.php
wp-load.php
wp-login.php
wp-mail.php
wp-settings.php
wp-signup.php
wp-trackback.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend the filename with a slash `/` to only match files in the repository root. That is, your `.gitignore` should look like:

```
#WordPress core files
wp-admin
wp-includes
/xmlrpc.php
index.php
...
```

Add a `/` before all the filenames that this applies to.

Answer (score 0):

One has to be careful during a git add, else you may end up adding files that you didn’t want to commit. However, git rm will remove it from both your staging area (index), as well as your file system (working tree), which may not be what you want.

remove the file using git rm xmlrpc.php rather then using git reset filename          # or echo xmlrpc.php >> .gitingore # add it to .gitignore to avoid re-adding it